# Change error system message in oracle apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a form page and all field is required when press save the below message appear 
[image: error message]

How i can change this message to custom message "please fill all required fields " , and how i can clear error when enter value (when value change to not null).

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if you can change system messages but you can add custom error messages  with javascript if a change happens in any item.

Add a change event to the item that runs javascript and use the following code:

```
var item = apex.item('P1_ITEM').getValue();

if(item == null) {
  //First clear the errors
  apex.message.clearErrors();

  // Now show new errors
  apex.message.showErrors([
    {
        type:       "error",
        location:   [ "page", "inline" ],
        pageItem:   "P1_ITEM",
        message:    "Name is required!",
        unsafe:     false
    },
    {
        type:       "error",
        location:   "page",
        message:    "Page error has occurred!",
        unsafe:     false
    }
  ]);
}
```

However, this will not stop the user from submitting, it only allows you to better display the messages, so you must add the corresponding validations after submit.

> If you want to remove the system error message from the required items, you can disable the option of `Value Required` on item and add a custom validation as they told you in the other response.

If you want to explore all the `apex.message` options better, I recommend this documentation:

https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/AEAPI/apex-message-namespace.htm#AEAPI-GUID-D15040D1-6B1A-4267-8DF7-B645ED1FDA46

More documentation for `apex.item`:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E71588_01/AEAPI/apex-item.htm#AEAPI29448

Comment: Thanks for your support,  is it possible remove  error message which is appears below item when value change apex.message.clearerrors remove all error is screen  how i can only remove specific error

Comment: According to the documentation there is no way to delete a single message, it only remains to delete everything and re-add all the messages that are needed.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see images at the moment.

However, one option might be to create your own validation which returns error text. Something like

```
if :P1_NAME is null then
   return ('Name must be entered');
end if;
```

Messages are automatically cleared once you submit the page and there are no errors left.

Comment: Ok, but I need change the popup system message  , and clear error when fill field "when change and item not null"

Answer (score 1):

There are some ways for how to do such things.
Firstly you have the custom Validations you can make, these are awesome and you should really try to use them if possible.

Then there is also the Error message on the saving procedure, but this just throws a custom message on procedure fail so I never use it.

What you appear to be seeing there is that you got an error message and didnt change the fields associated with the error.

If the save procedure is custom, you can also put in an EXCEPTION block before the END, and catch errors there and throw out a custom error with a custom error message.

Another thing I really like is to actually rename some common errors so I dont have to catch them all individually. Say clients may often times try to save identical data, thus breaking the PK. Oracle will throw an error, but the message is good for the developer, but less understandable for the client whom I always assume is a 3 year old kid who can barely read and will cry over everything. So I make an error handling function, add it to apex, and so when the error occurs, it throws a nice message informing the client that they have tried to add some data that already exists. 
So, an error handling function associated with APEX, to rename some normal errors.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for your support, is it possible remove error message which is appears below item when value change apex.message.clearerrors remove all error is screen how i can only remove specific error